# Add prefix to a line from the line before it in shell

Tags: shell, awk, grep, lines, prefix

I am executing following command to get the lines that have to be added prefix to from the line above it as follows:

```
 grep -B1 "^E[0-9]"
```

and I am getting something as follows:

```
ENSG00000165661:E5.1
E6.1
--
ENSG00000174776:E7.1
E8.1
--
ENSG00000122482:E7.2
E8.1
```

How do I add prefix to the lines that start with E[alphanumeric] such that the file becomes

```
 ENSG00000165661:E5.1
 ENSG00000165661:E6.1
 ENSG00000174776:E7.1
 ENSG00000174776:E8.1
 ENSG00000122482:E7.2
 ENSG00000122482:E8.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 awk -F: '/^E[0-9]/{print p0; print p1 FS $0} {p1=$1; p0=$0}' file
```

untested since no testable data

**Explanation**

when pattern match print the previous line stored in variable `p0`; then print the first field (`p1`) of the previous line, field separator (`FS`) and the current line (`$0`).  The next statement will set the `p0` and `p1` variables for each line whether it will be used or not since there is no look ahead.

Comment: well, the grep output can act as test data :P in which case this works :)

Comment: This is nice. Could you explain it a little bit? I am struggeling about, that you print a variable before assign a value to that variable. This is my ugly workaround, which provide the same output. `sed '/--/d' file | awk -F':' '{ if (NF==2) {suf=$1; print  } } { if (NF==1) {print suf FS $1} }'`